# Kendo Grid disable server refresh

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid that uses the local data source from the model on the view rather than making an ajax call. When I click on the headers though there is clearly a call to refresh the data. I have managed to prevent this using:

```
.DataSource(p => p.Custom().ServerSorting(false))
```

The problem I have with this though is that I have a 'select all' function built into the header which, when this code is added, converts all of my checkboxes into true/false text. Here is the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ContractLine>(Model.StockList)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(col =>
  {
    col.Bound(c => c.OffHire).Template(c => c.OffHireFlag == "Y" ? "<input type='checkbox' class='myCheck' data-lineref='" + c.ContractlineNo + "' />" : "").HeaderTemplate(f => ("<input id='checkAll' type='checkbox' class='check-box' onclick='checkAll(this)' /> &nbsp;<b>Request Off Hire</b>"));                                                        
    col.Bound(c => c.StockName).Title("Item Name");
    ...
  })
  .Filterable()
  .Sortable()
  .DataSource(p => p.Custom().ServerSorting(false))
```

basically if I comment out this last line then the checkboxes show fine. If I add the line about not going back to the server then the checkboxes show initially but clearly there is an event firing that converts them into true or false.

Comment: Why don't you use an Ajax call or a server binding data source? The local binding is normally used when your grid is just a simple table with static data.

Comment: @ataravati I believe `Model.StockList` is the *static data*.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, what I meant was he'd better not use a local datasource in this case. He has a template column in his grid. Also, the grid is both sortable an filterable.